# Spring Boot SOAP Response to JSON - Any plugin or any logic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Need to convert SOAP Response in SpringBoot (WebServivetemplate) to REST JSON.
Currently SOAP Response is working fine...need to convert this as JSON input /output. Any logic in spring framework other than looping through XML document node by node.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to change your own (server) endpoints or how you can parse XML messages received?

Comment: SOAP is XML. So not sure if I understand correctly. Just marshal to an object, return that object from your controller and Spring will convert it to JSON. You are likely overthinking this.

Comment: Ok Thanks... I need to work on JSON input data mapping to java request objects (Generated from WSDL)...... Please suggest me if any other options

Answer (score 0):

follwoing is good example how can you directly convert it using jaxb

```
 import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller(){
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in
    // pom.xml
    marshaller.setContextPath("phoneverify.wsdl");
    return marshaller;
}
```

- https://github.com/kennymarlo-private/spring-boot-rest-consume-soap/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/wsdl/wsdl/demo/config/WsdlConfiguration.java

Comment: Thanks..I have done the above part... I need to work on JSON input data mapping to java request objects (Generated from WSDL)......